# Mac OS X - Linking executable to different dynamic library, load both old and new

Tags: objective-c, macos, dyld, otool, install-name-tool

I've a command line tool, I built with Xcode, that links to some Apple frameworks.

As a "personal experiment" (just trying to understand a little of how dynamic libraries works) I tried to point the executable to a different version of the same frameworks.

Let's say for example that the executable **EXEC** uses **LIB_A** and the latter makes use of **LIB_B**.

I've made a copy of both **LIB_A** and **LIB_B** placing them under a different (shorter) directory path.

I used `otool -L` to get the dependencies and the ids of the libraries.

I then used `install_name_tool` with directive `-id` to change ids of new **LIB_A** and **LIB_B** (basically just changing the leading path as the name didn't changed).

Then with directive `-change` I let the new **LIB_A** to point to the new **LIB_B** and to let the executable **EXEC** to point to the new **LIB_A**.

This way, I thought, the whole dependency tree should have been correctly recreated.

---

`install_name_tool` didn't returned errors and inspecting the executable and the new libraries with `otool` they all point to the right path.

Unfortunately running the executable **EXEC** many errors are thrown to the console regarding duplicate definition of classes. Just as the old libraries and the new ones were loaded both.

Finally everything crash with **Trace/BPT trap: 5**

For example:

```
objc[25992]: Class NSAppleEventManager is implemented in both 
             /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation and
             /xyz/Foundation.
             One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

If I invoke

```
export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1
```

I see at execution that actually libraries are loaded twice.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the issue by brutally setting

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=
```

That worked for my particular situation.